# C++ XInput Compilation using g++

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, mingw, xinput

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <XInput.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Controller{
    XINPUT_STATE state;
};

class Joypad
{
public:
    int getJoystickPort()
    {
        DWORD dwResult;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < XUSER_MAX_COUNT; i++)
        {
            XINPUT_STATE state;
            ZeroMemory(&state, sizeof(XINPUT_STATE));   

            // Simply get the state of the controller from XInput.
            dwResult = XInputGetState(i, &state);

            if (dwResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                return((int) i);
                cout << "Joystick Port: " << i << " is connnected." << endl;
                cout << "Button " << (((int)state.Gamepad.wButtons == XINPUT_GAMEPAD_A)) << " pressed." << endl;
                cout << "LX:  " << state.Gamepad.sThumbLX << " LY: " << state.Gamepad.sThumbLY << endl;
                cout << "RX:  " << state.Gamepad.sThumbRX << " RY: " << state.Gamepad.sThumbRY << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Joystick at Port: " << i << " is disconnected." << endl;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};



void joystickStates(){
    Joypad* joypad = new Joypad;
    while (true){
        system("cls");      
        joypad->getJoystickPort();
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

int main(){
    joystickStates();
    return 0;
}
```

im getting the __in & __out 's was not declared in this scope errors.

I used the syntax below g++ Joypad.cpp -IC:\DirectSDK\Include -LC:\DirectSDK\Lib\x86 -lXinput -o Joypad

and I also tried 
g++ Joypad.cpp -IC:\Windows SDK~um,shared, etc -LC:\Windows SDK\Lib -lXInput -o Joypad

Is there something I missed? I use mingw x86_64

> Directories included:
>       Windows Kits 8.1 (um,shared,winrt)
>       Microsoft DirectX SDK
>
> Libraries included: XInput.lib - C:\Progra~2\Micros~4\Lib\x86

Comment: error is at http://pastebin.com/mJen909T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__in` and `__out` are Microsoft-specific [SAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
annotations. They are understood by the MS Visual Studio C++ compiler but not by the GCC compiler.

A way to "delete" them would be to make yourself a header file, say, `no_sal.h` and
every time your GCC compilation barfs on a SAL annotation `__foo`, add:

```
#define __foo
```

to `no_sal.h`. Then make sure that `no_sal.h` is included first in every compilation
by passing `g++` the option `-include /path/to/no_sal.h`.

However, I would not expect this to be the end of your problems in attempting to
compile such very "deeply Microsoft" code as the DirectX SDK with GCC. If you
don't want to use Visual Studio then consider switching your Windows GCC
distribution from MinGW (I guess) to [TDM GCC 64-bit](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/),
which bundles DirectX headers and libraries for GCC.

Comment: Thank you sir it successfully compiled.. but doesn't seem to work like I thought it would. I used x360ce to support my generic twin usb, it didnt work, It doesnt recognize it. 

btw, this program works fine when I use visual studio to compile it and use x360ce to recognize my joypad.